# Using an already instance of Word

Tags: c#

I have never programmed in C# or visual studio,  I figured the only way to get started was to dive in and experience the hurt and the pain and solve problems as they arise.  Please forgive the my remedial questions and my lack of inexperience.

I have the following code below which opens an application if it is not already open. Also returns the process ID (just in case i needed it) Once the application is open,  code set 2 prints a document to the default printer,  which is set prior to opening the application.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ImageIT.PreFlight
{
    public class AppCheck
    {
        public int IsAppOpen (string appCheck)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We are in APPCHECK");
            var appToStart = Process.GetProcessesByName(appCheck);
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            var appID = 0;

            if (appToStart.Length == 0)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = appCheck,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    Arguments = "/q /n /x",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                };
                Process.Start(startInfo);
                appID = Process.GetProcessesByName(appCheck)[0].Id;
                Console.WriteLine(appCheck + " Has been Starterd - Process ID: " + appID);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                    if (theprocess.ProcessName == appCheck)
                    {
                        appID = theprocess.Id;
                        Console.WriteLine(appCheck + " Has been found - Process ID: " + appID);
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
            }
            return appID;
        }
    } 
}
```

Code Set 2

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;


namespace ImageIT.AppPrint
{

    public class PrintToImage
    {

        public void PrintWordDocument(string fileToPrint, int wordID)
        {
            object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Console.WriteLine("We are Currently in PrintToImage");
            Console.WriteLine("The current Word INSTANCE ID is: "+ wordID);
            //Word.Application objWord = new Word.Application();


            Word.Application objWord = (Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application;
            //objWord = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application;


            Word.Document objDoc = new Word.Document();

            //object fileName = fileToPrint;
            //Console.WriteLine("File to Print:" + fileToPrint);

            //objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
            //    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
            //    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
            //    ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);

            //object copies = "1";
            //object pages = "";
            //object range = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
            //object items = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent;
            //object pageType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;
            //object objTrue = true;
            //object objFalse = false;

            //objDoc.PrintOut(
            //    ref objTrue, ref objFalse, ref range, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
            //    ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref objFalse, ref objTrue,
            //    ref objMissing, ref objFalse, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);

            //objDoc.Close(ref objFalse, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
        }


    }
}
```

If i use

```
//Word.Application objWord = new Word.Application();
```

a new instance of MS-Word is open and the document prints to an image as expected. Potentially, there will be hundreds files to images so I am a trying avoid this.

The best article i could find on how to accomplish this  is

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eric_carter/2009/03/12/attaching-to-an-already-running-office-application-from-your-application-using-getactiveobject-or-bindtomoniker/

However when try

```
//objWord = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application;
```

i receive "the name objWord does not exist in this current context"

I change  it to

```
Word.Application objWord = (Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application;
```

And the application crashes.

Note: most of the lines have been commented out for testing.

Any assistance it greatly appreciated, thank you advance.

Comment: "I have never programmed in C# or visual studio, I figured the only way to get started was to dive in and experience the hurt and the pain and solve problems as they arise." That's fine - until you start diving in using ActiveX right from the start. I'd *strongly* advise you to start with something much, much simpler - learn with simple console apps, then move onto Word interop when you've got a strong foundation.

Comment: the exception message would be pretty useful!

Comment: Actually - this is just a console app although it is changing  windows settings. There are no GUI's windows or Prompts. all is running much as a simple script and learning the Word Interop is exactly what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unhandled Exception:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(Guid& rclsid, IntPtr reserved, Object& ppunk)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)
   at ImageIT.AppPrint.PrintToImage.PrintWordDocument(String fileToPrint, Int32 wordID) in C:\Users\ylafont\source\repos\ImageIT\ImageIT\AppPrint\PrintToImage.cs:line 27

Comment: at ImageIT.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ylafont\source\repos\ImageIT\ImageIT\Program.cs:line 35

Comment: Interop is old and often difficult to work with, especially as a beginner. If you want to have a solid skillset modifying Office documents then learn OpenXML instead.

Comment: noted , will place it on the todo list. nothing is being modified. Just reading and printing a file to the default printer. Sure will need to get total page pages printed for other purposed -but no modifications whats so ever,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the assistance - I was not to far off on my initial attempt and there was a visual  studio bug that was corrected with the latest 15.5.1 update  --- line was modified to -->
`Word.Application objWord = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application`;